# Place static javascript code on all pages

Tags: magento

Im new to Magento. I would like to know how can I place static javascript code across all pages of the magento site. The JS code does some initilization and includes another hosted js file. Also, I would like to add this code in footer of all pages.

Any guidance/docs/codes welcomed.

Thnx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The fastest way is to create a new file in the "js" folder in the root
>   of your website. To include the Javascript file in the code, go to
>
> ```
> System -> Configuration -> Design -> Footer -> Miscellaneous Scripts
> ```
>
> And add your script there like you would normally do.
>
> There are other ways, but this is the easiest way to do it.
>
> *Edit: Changed HTML head to Footer, thanks dagfr*

**- Edit -**

The above example is not what he meant, he wants to add JS to the footer, so when he distributes the module, the JS will also be in the footer.

**Answer**

You can use the layout .xml file for your module to add a JS file.
To do this, you can add the following code:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>script_name_here.js</name></action>
```

In order to place it in the footer, you will have to make a new block, which is explained in [the following article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130319030627/http://plorp.com/blog/how-to-load-javascript-in-the-footer-in-magento-1-4-2).

Comment: This is not the FOOTER. `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Footer -> Miscellaneous HTML` will better fit your needs ;)

Comment: Seems ok, only thing is that i have to make this available through a module distributed through magento marketplace. How should i change above ?

Comment: The above can be found in the admin and is default Magento ^_^
And i overlooked the footer part of his question dagfr, thanks for the correction! I have editted the post! ;)

Comment: I read your comment too fast and didn't see you wanted it to be available with a module you're distributing. :o

Comment: Make a module with a setup, and make this module run a sql queries to feed this field (in core_config_data, row with path = design_footer_absolute_footer